# c++ reverse line using stack compile error no operator matches operand

Tags: c++, stack, operators, reverse

I'm writing a program to reverse the string using a stack. I'm getting 2 errors in my code. 1. no operator >> matches the operand 2. On the line Reverse(string); it errors say (string)type name is not allowed. Any idea why?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stack>        
using namespace std;

void Reverse(char);

int main()
{
    char object;

    cout << "Please enter a line of text.\n";
    cin >> object;

    char * point = new char[object.length() + 1];
    strcpy(point, object.c_str());
    Reverse(point);

    Reverse(point);

    printf(" %s", object);

    system("pause");

    return 0;


}

void Reverse(char *p)
{
    stack<char> S;


    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(p); i++)
        S.push(p[i]);


    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(p); i++)
    {
        p[i] = S.top();
        S.pop();
    }
}
```

updated code: error on cin >> object says the initial question no operator matches an operand

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stack>        
using namespace std;

void Reverse(string);

int main()
{
    string object;

    cout << "Please enter a line of text.\n";
    cin >> object;

    char * point = new char[object.length() + 1];
    strcpy(point, object.c_str());

    Reverse(point);

    printf(" %s", point);

    system("pause");

    return 0;


}

void Reverse(char *p)
{
    stack<char> S;


    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(p); i++)
        S.push(p[i]);


    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(p); i++)
    {
        p[i] = S.top();
        S.pop();
    }
}
```

I am getting error strcpy_s does not take 2 arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stack>        
using namespace std;

void Reverse(char *p)
{
    stack<char> S;


    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(p); i++)
        S.push(p[i]);


    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(p); i++)
    {
        p[i] = S.top();
        S.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    string object;

    cout << "Please enter a line of text.\n";
    cin >> object;

    char * point = new char[object.length() + 1];
    strcpy_s(point, object.c_str());

    Reverse(point);

    printf(" %s", point);

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `string` and `char *` are not the same thing.

Comment: thanks so if i change Reverse (string) to Reverse (char) i get type name not allowed

Comment: are you trying to pass `string object` to `Reverse()`?

Comment: it would now be char object i'm trying to pass. I changed all string to char. Was that the wrong direction to take?

Comment: `void Reverse(string)` needs be `void Reverse(char *)` the types need to match if your still getting that cin >> error that is because of your header file `#include <string.h>` which is a c library use `#include <string>`

Comment: You also need to `#include <cstring>` because your using `strcpy`

Comment: compile error gone, but now get this error which terminates the program Exception thrown at 0x0FF1125C (ucrtbased.dll) in Project5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000006C.

Comment: [here](http://rextester.com/live/FSUX16702)

Comment: the code provided does not compile. same error operator must have class type

Answer (score 1):

```
char * point = new char[object.length()+1];//+1 for the null terminator 
strcpy(point, object.c_str());
Reverse(point);
printf("%s",point);
```

allocates space for point then copies http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy and you were calling Reverse like this `Reverse(char)` you need to call it using the name of the char variable like this `Reverse(point);` since we allocated space we need to delete it after we are done using it.

Comment: Do I create a new void class? Not sure where I implement this in the code.

Comment: can you edit your question to what it looks like after you changed the code?

Comment: okay there are several problems 1st `char object` needs to be `string object` 2nd you are calling `Reverse(point)` two times you only need to do that one time change `printf("%s", object);` to `printf("%s", point);`

Answer (score -1):

Please check the modified code below. I can reverse the input string now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>        
using namespace std;

void Reverse(char *p)
{
    stack<char> S;


    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(p); i++)
        S.push(p[i]);


    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(p); i++)
    {
        p[i] = S.top();
        S.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    string object;

    cout << "Please enter a line of text.\n";
    cin >> object;

    char * point = new char[object.length() + 1];
    strcpy(point, object.c_str());

    Reverse(point);

    printf(" %s", point);

    system("pause");

    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: You need to delete that memory you allocated for `char* point`

Comment: This code gives me error with strcpy function does not take 2 arguments. When I delete the line of strcpy... The program does not run.

Comment: @CVYCCVYC strcpy is supposed to take 2 arguments did you `#include <cstring>` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy

Comment: @tyger my compiler forces me to use strcpy_s, when using strcpy I get an error saying unsafe. When i use strcpy_s it says 2 arguments. yes i have #include <cstring>